# Execute commands while waiting MeetMe() to add caller to conference or Timeout is up

Tags: asterisk

How to execute `Playback()` or `Background()` command in asterisk while waiting for `MeetMe()`
response or Timeout

what I'm trying to do is to `Playback()` sound file randomly every 40 sec till `MeetMe()` add caller to queue 
or Timeout get done (Note: Timeout is 3 minutes)

```
 exten => s,n(live),Set(TIMEOUT(absolute)=180)
 exten => s,n,MeetMe(130989,wmqdT1)
 exten => s,n,Set(promptnum=${PathPrompts}/${RAND(38,42)})
 exten => s,n,Background(${promptnum})

 ;Timeout 
 exten => T,1(timeout),Playback(${PathPrompts}/30)
 exten => T,n,Playback(${PathPrompts}/31)
 exten => T,n,Playback(${PathPrompts}/38)
 exten => T,n,Playback(${PathPrompts}/60)
 exten => T,n,Playback(${PathPrompts}/55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hold music and M(holdclass) flag

```
  M[(class)]: Enable music on hold when the conference has a single
    caller. Optionally, specify a musiconhold class to use. If one is not
    provided, it will use the channel's currently set music class, or 'de
    fault'.
```

So just create long gile with your prompts and silense.

Other option is spy channel and playback on it(require expert level)

For timout you can use this option:

```
w[(secs)]: Wait until the marked user enters the conference.
```

After that use marked user flag on entry next user

```
A: Set marked mode.
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but `M[(class)]` option plays music only while I need to play Prompts ...

Comment: Concatenate prompt+silence(40sec)+prompt and you got what you want. All other solutions require expert level, not think it can be easy described

Answer (score 0):

Use ConfBridge instead of MeetMe

http://lists.digium.com/pipermail/asterisk-users/2009-May/231433.html